# flex:1, display:flex on the same element?

Tags: css, flexbox

I cannot find reliable information online or in caniuse website.

Is it 'legal' and well supported to use display: flex on a flexbox item? I mean:

```
.parent{
   display: flex;
}

.child{
   flex:1;
   display: flex;
}
```

And do you maybe know of any browser support chart?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. It's not basic flexbox.

Comment: This is legit to use and is referred as _nested_ flex containers. Any browser that support `display: flex` support _nested_ containers

Comment: The cops are here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of "support".

`display:flex` makes an element a "flex-parent".

`flex: 1` applies **only** to "flex-children".

It's entirely "legal" because the two properties don't apply for the same reasons and aren't *specifically* related.

For information on *nested flexboxes*, you can refer to the [**W3.org Specification**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abstract)*

<sup>* Thanks to LGSon</sup>

Comment: Ok, but do you know of any info about browser support? I mean, if I use this, will it be correctly interpreted by browsers? What browsers? This specific information seems not to be available on caiuse.

Comment: Your basic question is nothing to do with support.. If a browser supports flexbox it supports both those properties.

Comment: @Stratboy The official info about nested boxes is here, [https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abstract](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abstract), so you can safely accept this answer :)